# SQLite out of memory exception

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, synchronized

I am getting the "java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_MISUSE]  Library used incorrectly (out of memory)". I paste the code sample for my database connection object

```
public class DBhandler {
   private String DBUrl="d:\\sqlitedb\\somdb.db";
   private String driverName="org.sqlite.JDBC";
   private String jdbc="jdbc:sqlite:";
   private Connection con=null;
   private Statement stmnt=null;

  public DBhandler() 
  {
        try {
            Class.forName(this.driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

            try {
                this.con=DriverManager.getConnection(this.jdbc+this.DBUrl);
                this.stmnt=con.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

  }

   public CurrentActiveSom getCurrentActiveSom()
 {

     CurrentActiveSom cas=null;
     String query="select * from current_active_som where active=1"; 
    ResultSet rs=null;

     try {
        rs=this.stmnt.executeQuery(query);
    if (rs.next())
    {
        cas= new CurrentActiveSom();
        cas.setMonth(rs.getString("month"));
        cas.setYear(rs.getString("year"));
        cas.setIsActive(rs.getInt("active"));

    }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     finally
     {
         try {
            rs.close();
            this.stmnt.close();
             this.con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
     return cas;
 }

 public CurrentActiveSom getIsDoneSom(String month,String year)
 {

     CurrentActiveSom cas=null;
     String query="select * from current_active_som where month='"+month+"' and year='"+year+"' and active=0"; 

    ResultSet rs=null;


     try {

             rs=this.stmnt.executeQuery(query); //this is exception line
        }

        if (rs.next())
        {
            cas= new CurrentActiveSom();
            cas.setMonth(rs.getString("month"));
            cas.setYear(rs.getString("year"));
            cas.setIsActive(rs.getInt("active"));

        }


     } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

     finally
     {
         try {
            //rs.close(); //if i uncomment this gets null pointer exception 
            this.stmnt.close();
             this.con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
     return cas;
 }
```

The call to these Two methods with same object of DBhandler like

```
 DBhandler db=new DBhandler();
 CurrentActiveSom cas1=db.getCurrentActiveSom();
 CurrentActiveSom cas2=db.getIsDoneSom(String month,String year)
```

then I am getting the above exception ,

but if we call thses 2 methods with different object DBhandler like

```
   DBhandler db1=new DBhandler();
   DBhandler db2=new DBhandler();
   CurrentActiveSom cas1=db1.getCurrentActiveSom();
   CurrentActiveSom cas2=db2.getIsDoneSom(String month,String year)
```

Then code is working fine.

Is this because of sync problem, with connection ? how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the "out of memory"error looks weird, but one definitive error lies in creating `Connection` once per program run (in the constructor) and then closing it in each data access method.

This code:

```
CurrentActiveSom cas1=db.getCurrentActiveSom();
```

closes the `Connection`, so this code:

```
CurrentActiveSom cas2=db.getIsDoneSom(String month,String year)
```

tries to get data from a *closed* database. This is OK if you are using some kind of connection pooling in which closing a connection returns it to the pool. But it seems you're working on a single physical connection.

So just close it after you're done getting data from DB, and not in each data access method.

Comment: so should i do connection closing this in finalize() ?

Comment: `finalize()` is a whole different story, I don't suggest you touch this method. Just make a `closeConnection()` method in `DBhandler` and put `con.close()` in this method. Then call in order: `new DBhandler()`, data access methods, and then `DBHandler.close()`. Also, you need to create your `Statement` objects each time in data access methods, not once in `DBHandler`.

Comment: If you want to know more about finalization, look here: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/finalization/ Bottom line of the article is: Use Finalization Only When You Must. It's not really a reliable method of doing cleanup.

Answer (score -1):

You close connection before you call `rs.next()so ResultSet try to read from connection, that has been already closed.